# What is a bidirectional iterator in C++?

Tags: c++

bidirectional iterator means whether it has support to reverse_iterator or like iterator which         will point to end of the vector and decrementing iterator like below program.

```
int main()
{
   std::vector<int> myvector;
   std::vector<int>::iterator it;
   myvector.push_back(10);
   myvector.push_back(101);
   myvector.push_back(100);
   for(it = --myvector.end();it!= myvector.begin();--it)
          cout<<*it<<endl;  
}
```

Comment: What did you find when you asked your preferred search engine about "bidirectional iterator"? Which part of that would you like help with?

Comment: or just use rbegin and rend.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator

Comment: Or §24.2.6 of the standard, which this margin is too small to contain.

Comment: It seems like you answered your own question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Vector will support Bidirectional iteator, but in one of C++ book, they discussed vector supports only RandomAccess iterator?

Comment: @user3665615: __C++ 2011 Section 24.2.7 Random access iterators. Paragraph 1:__ _A class or pointer type X satisfies the requirements of a random access iterator if, in addition to satisfying the requirements for bidirectional iterators, the following expressions are valid as shown in Table 111._ In other words, random access iterators implement everything that bidirectional iterators implement.

Comment: @sharth, So All sequential and Associative containers will support Bidirectional Iterators. Is my statement is correct?

Comment: @user3665615: No. For example, a `std::forward_list` only has a forward iterator. All sequential containers will use atleast a forward-iterator. Associative containers will use bidirectional-iterators though.

Comment: @sharth: except std::forward_list, remaining sequential containers supports bidirectional iterators. am I correct?

Comment: @user3665615: Yes. I believe that is correct.

Answer (score 5):

A bidirectional iterator has nothing special to do with `std::vector::rbegin()` or `std::vector::rend()`.

> ## C++ 2011 24.2.6 Bidirectional iterators
>
> A class or pointer type X satisfies the requirements of a bidirectional iterator if, in addition to satisfying the requirements for forward iterators, the following expressions are valid as shown in Table 110.
>
> Table 110 requires the following expressions to be valid: 
>   `--r`,
>   `r--`, and
>   `*r--`

And if you'd like, here's a copy of the relevant page:

[image: Section 24.2.6 from the C++ 2011 Standard]